# How can I get current atmospheric pressure for my latitude and longitude?

Tags: android, weather, weather-api, pressure

I want to get current atmospheric pressure given a latitude and longitude from some kind of remote service, so I can compare it to the pressure sensor's reading and come up with an altitude.

Unfortunately TWC and and World Weather Online have usage limits, like only a few hundred requests per day per API key, which won't work if more than a handful of users download my app and are all using it at once with the same API key in the code.  After 5 minutes no user will be able to get any data.  So I need a way of querying the data without usage limits.  Is there a service that provides this without making you get an API key?

Comment: don't they provide Paid account with unlimited Queries?

Answer (score 0):

Hey bro have you thought looking into the altimeter that comes w the phone? I remember from Science class that all they do is measure the pressure of the atmosphere same as altimeter. Maybe you could make a btree and figure out the correct indexes along the way.